# How to visit router's global ip-address inside the router's intranet?

Tags: ip, router

I have my home's network connected to internet through a router, which is with a global ip address. 
There is a web site on this ip using port-mapping, and everything works OK when accessing from outside. 
The problem is I cannot visit my web site through this global ip-address inside my intranet. 
Is there anyway to forward a global ip as a local ip? 
for ex: when I try to access 211.11.11.11, it automatically forwards to 192.168.0.1, so that I can access my website in home.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the webserver by navigating directly to `192.168.0.1` or whatever local ip the webserver is running on.

Comment: I can access it using 192.168.0.1, but there are some hard code in flash or silverlight which fetch service from my global ip address.